# Jedis Vs Spring Data Redis Vs Reddison - which one to prefer when you've some complex query logic?

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, reddison

I am new to `Redis` and trying to understand on the following things -

1) Which connector we should use when we have to perform some complex queries -

```
   a) Jeddision
   b) Spring Data Redis
   c) Reddison
```

2) How to model data into Redis, if you want to convert all your Spring Data JPA (Entity classes and Repository) quires into Redis?

I have seen that in Spring Data Redis, https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories.queries, Table 9 says that you can only support few queries.

[image]